# How to convert string into Date format?

Tags: apex, date, datetime

I have  3strings. I want to convert it into date

How to achieve this ?

```
string a='20';
string b='4';
string c='1993';

String dt = DateTime.newInstance(a,b,c).format('d-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, the way you were headed it's something like this:

`String dt = Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(c),Integer.valueOf(b),Integer.valueOf(a)).format();`

Keep in mind:

- The `newInstance` method takes Integers as parameters
- `format()` will format the date in the current user's locale

Read more on [Date Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

Comment: Nice point. Since the OP doesn't ask for a String as the output, even .format() is not necessary here. And although it is not necessary in this case, I usually use .trim() before using Integer.valueOf() just for more safety.

Answer (score 1):

```
string year = '1993';
string month = '4';
string day = '20';

string stringDate = year + '-' + month
 + '-' + day ;

Date myDate = date.valueOf(stringDate);

system.debug('mapPeriodDay>>>'+myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Made this change in your existing code

```
DateTime.newInstance(integer.valueof(c),integer.valueof(b),integer.valueof(a)).format('dd-MM-YYYY');
```